# Connectedness of fibers of a map related to the secant variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subsetneq\mathbb{P}^{N}$ be a smooth projective variety, and let 
$$
S_{X}=\overline{\{(x,y,z)\in X\times X\times \mathbb{P}^{N}:x\neq y, z\in\langle x,y\rangle\}}.
$$
The secant variety of $X$ is defined to be
$$
SX:=\varphi(S_{X}),
$$
where $\varphi:S_{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N}$ is the projection to the third factor. I wonder if $\varphi^{-1}(x)$ is connected for $x\in X$. In case it is not true in general, is there any easy condition that we should impose in $X$ or $SX$ for it to hold?

For example, if $\varphi$ is birational and every $x\in X$ is normal at $SX$, then it holds because of Zariski's Main Theorem. I am looking for weaker conditions that may imply the connectedness of $\varphi^{-1}(x)$.

What if 
$$
\dim X:=n=\frac{2}{3}(N-2)
$$
 and 
$$
\dim\varphi^{-1}(x)=n
$$
 for general $x\in X$?

$\textbf{Remark:}$ In fact, $\dim\varphi^{-1}(x)=n$ always holds for general $x\in X$. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238476/preimage-of-a-variety-in-the-incidence-correspondence-associated-to-its-secant-v) question for more details.

Comment: The fibers can certainly fail to be connected, e.g., for any linearly nondegenerate  space curve $X\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$ and genus $g < (d-2)(d-3)/2-1$ (say $d=5$ and $g=0$).

Comment: Further if the secant variety isn't normal, that may provide counter examples.

Comment: @JasonStarr I have edited the question adding a possible extra hypothesis. I would appreciate if you could take a look. Thank you :).